# Java application startup - how first object is created

Tags: java, object, classloader

When we run a Java application, we know that the first object to be loaded is `java.lang.Object`. However, `java.lang.Object` has methods which throw exceptions like `CloneNotSupportedException` or `InterruptedException`, which are in turn other objects.

The question is: when `java.lang.Object` is just getting loaded, how is it possible to have its child (for example exception objects) objects being already created?

Comment: By "created", I assume you mean "loaded"?

Comment: Yes created means loaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `loaded` and `instantiated`are two different things.

**Rough explanation:**

`loaded` means the JVM loaded a class into its base class loader. This makes the class available for *instantiation*. When JVM starts, it first loads all classes through the used/linked `jar` files, without *instantiating* them. This means, when the first `new Object()` is created, the exceptions which are used by `Object` are already known. This is still a declaration. The instance of the exception is created only when that particular exception is thrown.

For technically correct explanation see the link which @Jim Garrison has mentioned:

[JVM: Loading, Linking, and Initializing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html)

Comment: Thank You ! for answering in short and guiding .